# Confirming solution: Improper double integral

Tags: real-analysis

**The Problem**

Show that the improper double integral $I=\iint_{\mathbb R^2} (x-2y)^2 e^{-x^2+4xy-20y^2} \, d(x,y)$ converges and find its value.

**Solution Attempt**

We calculate that the integral converges to $\pi/8$. I'd like to confirm this answer, but Wolfram|Alpha won't load this integral.

- Completed the square in the exponent as $-(x - 2y)^2 - (4y)^2$
- Used coordinate transform $u = x - 2y$, $v = 4y$; $\det \text{Jacobian} =1/4$

So we have

$$I=\frac 14 \iint_{\mathbb R^2} u^2e^{-u^2-v^2} \,du\, dv$$

which becomes

$$I=\frac 14 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[ u^2e^{-u^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-v^2} dv\right] \, du = \frac 14 \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty u^2e^{-u^2} \, du \right) \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-v^2} \, dv \right)$$

We've shown in class that second integral is $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Then, integrating by parts with $p = u$, $dq = ue^{-u^2} du$, we get

$$I = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{4} \left[\underset{=0-0 \text{ by l'Hospital}}{\underbrace{\left(-\frac 12 ue^{-u^2}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty}} + \frac 12 \underset{=\sqrt \pi}{\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2} du}}\right]$$

Thus we get, $I = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{4} \cdot \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{8}$.

Can anyone confirm this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think it's right

Answer (score 1):

So far so good till the Jacobian. Then there is a trick that speeds up the computation. 
By symmetry,

$$ J=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} u^2 e^{-(u^2+v^2)}\,du\,dv = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} v^2 e^{-(u^2+v^2)}\,du\,dv = \frac{1}{2}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} (u^2+v^2)\, e^{-(u^2+v^2)}\,du\,dv $$
hence by switching to polar coordinates we get:
$$ J = \pi \int_{0}^{+\infty}\rho^3 e^{-\rho^2}\,d\rho =\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}u e^{-u}\,du=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\Gamma(2)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$